# Android Application will auto update when a new version is released on play store

Tags: java, android, google-play

I update the new version of my application in play store. Want to make auto update in those phone where the application is already installed. I did this work.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
}
```

and in `MainActivity` I did this work-

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String newVersion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new FetchAppVersionFromGooglePlayStore().execute();
    }

    class FetchAppVersionFromGooglePlayStore extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                return
                        Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + "com.directed.android.smartstart" + "&hl=en")
                        .timeout(10000)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                        .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                        .get()
                        .select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]")
                        .first()
                        .ownText();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "";
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
            newVersion = string;
            Log.d("new Version", newVersion);
        }
    }
}
```

But, still not working. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should leave it to the users, whether they want automatic updates for an app or not. Forcing updates onto your users, like you want to, is not nice.

Comment: But, how do user know there is a new version available on play store? Will application  inform users automatically without doing any work in my android code?

Comment: @ImtiazRiad Yes. The Google Play store (and afaik other stores like Amazon, Huawei, Samsung Galary) roll out updates over a certain time period (hours or days) to all users. If the user enabled auto update for all their apps, the app gets updated automatically. Otherwise they get a notification reading something like "XX apps are ready to update".

Comment: great. Thank you for informing me. I didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is to support in-app updates. As the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates) states, In-app updates shows a dialog to the user in case an update is available and it's the user's choice whether he/she wants to update it or not.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

I personally find it good because as an android developer, I want my users to stay updated considering privacy and security concerns. and it doesn't enforce user to update maintaining the UX.

This way you don't have to mess with JSOUP as it works with in-built `AppUpdateManager`. 
You should give it a read on the [official docs : Support in-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates).

**EDIT:** You can further set and check update priority evaluating the severity of update whether it's necessary. As official document states:

The Google Play Developer API allows you to set the priority of each update. This allows your app to decide how strongly to recommend an update to the user. For example, consider the following strategy for setting update priority:

> **Minor UI improvements:** Low-priority update; request neither a flexible
>   nor immediate update.
>
> **Performance improvements:** Medium-priority
>   update; request a flexible update.
>
> **Critical security update:** High-priority update; require an immediate update.
>
> To determine priority, Google Play uses an integer value between 0 and 5, with > 0 being the default, and 5 being the highest priority. To set the
>   priority for an update, use `inAppUpdatePriority` field under
>   Edits.tracks.releases in the Google Play Developer API. Priority can
>   only be set when rolling out a new release, and cannot be changed
>   later.

Priority is relevant because it will change the frequency of the update dialog visible to user as bothering user to update every time for minor update is not a good UX.

Comment: can you please help me where to set this `inAppUpdatePriority`  priority. because I don't find any way to set it from the application side.

Comment: @HarshadPrajapati Look at [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61115215/8244632). You can also look at [this thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133299031?pli=1#comment14) for some solution. It can only be done through APIs for now. From the application side, [this library](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher) can help